# what is the substitute of splunk eval in logql?

Tags: grafana, splunk, grafana-loki, logql

I have this expression in my splunk query eval A = A + '/' + B where A is the new variable (column name) to which I am assigning the values of A and B from my log line and I need to replace the same expression in loki grafana using logql.
Right now I am just getting two columns Time and {}. I want to replaace TIme column with eval expression. Can someone please help me on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent of variables in LogQL are labels.

Thus, you can use [`label_format`](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/log_queries/#labels-format-expression) to achieve what you want.

Here is an example of how to use `label_format` to perform a string concatenation of two labels, named `var_a` and `var_b`:

*Input:*

```json
{"var_a": "a", "var_b": "b", "message": "hello there!"}
```

*LogQL query*:

```
{service="my-awesome-app"}
  | json # or logfmt, depending on your log format
  | label_format var_a=`{{.var_a}}/{{.var_b}}` # this reassigns var_a based on the given template
```

*Output:*

```json
{"var_a": "a/b", "var_b": "b", "message": "hello there!"}
```